# Paypal, uniquely match started transaction with completed transaction

Tags: paypal

How can I uniquely match a call to SetExpressCheckout with the completed transaction (either GetExpressCheckoutDetails or DoExpressCheckoutPayment)?

I see that I can pass a product description (PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC) to SetExpressCheckout, which I can then retrieve from the GetExpressCheckoutDetails response (PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC). However, I'm not sure if I can use this as a unique identifier or if this is something that the buyer can see.

Also, what if the user chooses Cancel instead of Pay? Is there a way to match that up with the original call to SetExpressCheckout?

Comment: Is this an eCommerce site? Typically you don't match via tokens - you have some system in place already. The token is just for payment - once it is complete then you transfer the cart over using session id / invoice id or something.

Comment: I'm adding a payment option to a website. It seems strange if I can't track a transaction from when the user clicks "pay with paypal" on my website to the final transaction. I implemented Stripe for credit cards and they let you put in your own input fields, which they will pass along to you, along with the token. I use that to pass along a unique purchase_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM field in the SetExpressCheckout. According to documentation:

> A free-form field for your own use. You can specify up to 10 payments, where n is a digit between 0 and 9, inclusive

That field is not visible for the user and you can get it back in the response.

Same field can be send in all calls GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I give it as a parameter to SetExpressCheckout  and it comes out as a response to GetExpressCheckoutDetails.